# Map.contains vs Map.values().stream().filter.find

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, option-type

What are best practices related to checking if the Map contains an element since Java 8? I want to check if the Map contains an element and based on it get the object or create a new one and put it into the map. The functional way seems to be too verbose.

```
final private static Map<Integer, BowlingBall> pool = new HashMap<>();
int number = 8;
```

Imperative way:

```
BowlingBall ballImperative = null;

if (pool.containsKey(number)) {
    ballImperative = pool.get(number);
} else {
    ballImperative = new BowlingBall(number);
    pool.put(number, ballImperative);
}
```

Functional way:

```
BowlingBall ballFunctional = pool.values().stream()
    .filter(k -> k.getNumber() == number)
    .findAny()
    .orElseGet(() -> new BowlingBall(number));

pool.put(number, ballFunctional);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BowlingBall ballImperative =
    pool.computeIfAbsent(number, BowlingBall::new);
```

Much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8, there are two new methods available for this purpose:

[`Map#putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hello", "world");
map.putIfAbsent("hello", "Luiggi");
System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
```

[`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hello", "world");
map.computeIfAbsent("hello", s -> "Luiggi");
System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
```

The main difference between them is that the former evaluates the value to put before checking if the key already contains a value. The latter may be understood as a lazy set. Example:

```
public String createValue(String s) {
    System.out.println("value of s: " + s);
    return "hello " + s;
}


Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hello", "world");
//executing the line below will fire System.out.println from the method
map.putIfAbsent("hello", createValue("world"));
//executing the line below will not fire System.out.println from the method
map.computeIfAbsent("hello", s -> createValue("world"));
System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
```

For your case, the code can be reduced to:

```
pool.put(number, number -> new BowlingBall(number));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are more ways:

1. `Map::putIfAbsent`

   Here takes place [`Map::putIfAbsent(K key, V value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) instead of the 
   Stream which computes the value and puts with the key to the map if the key 
   is not present.

   ```
   map.putIfAbsent(1, new BollwingBall(number));
   ```
2. `Map::computeIfAbsent`

   The alternative way is [`Map::computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? 
   extends V> mappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) which uses a mapping function to compute the 
   value from the key. Works on the same principle as the method above.

   ```
   map.putIfAbsent(1, integer -> new BowlingBall(integer)); // the value is computed 
                                                            // from the key
   map.putIfAbsent(1, BowlingBall::new);                    // the shortened version of 
                                                            // the one above
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [Map.computeIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

From the doc:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

Eg:

```
BowlingBall ballImperative = 
          pool.computeIfAbsent(number, BowlingBall::new);
```